# pyQt5 program with multiple windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'am trying to make a program with multiple windows so that next window will open after clicking a pushbutton. Now i'm at this point where the first window works just fine and the second window opens BUT pushbuttons doesn't work.

Edit:The button in the second window does nothing when the window is opened from the first one but when the class "Second" is called by its own and not from the first window, it works.

Here is the important parts from the class for the first window:

```py
class Aloitus(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitAloitus()

    def InitAloitus(self):
        self.button=QPushButton("Ok",self)
        self.button.move(200,200)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.continue)
        self.setGeometry(600,200,500,300)
        self.show()

    def continue(self):
        self.close()
        next=Second()
        next.__init__()
```

And here is the class for second window:

```py
class Second(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title="Alkutiedot"
        self.top=600
        self.left=200
        self.width=500
        self.height=500

        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.button=QPushButton("Ok", self)
        self.button.move(100,400)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.ok)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    def ok(self):
        self.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you click the buttons on the second window?

Comment: Nothing. Weird thing is that the button in the second window actually works when the class "Second" is called by its own and not from the first window

Comment: remove `next.__init__()`

Comment: Do `self.next = Second()`, otherwise the second window will get garbage-collected before it can be shown.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. Problem was the way I was calling the second window

Answer (score 2):

3 Things:

1. change the name of the function to something else than "continue" [continue is taken](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)
2. remove the explicit `__init__` call, its called by the constructor.
3. change the line `next=Second()` to `self.next=Second()` to avoid garbage collection

   ```
   class Aloitus(QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.InitAloitus()

       def InitAloitus(self):
           self.button=QPushButton("Ok",self)
           self.button.move(200,200)
           self.button.clicked.connect(self.continue2)
           self.setGeometry(600,200,500,300)
           self.show()

       def continue2(self):
           self.close()
           self.next=Second()
           #next.__init__()

   class Second(QMainWindow):

       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.title="Alkutiedot"
           self.top=600
           self.left=200
           self.width=500
           self.height=500

           self.initWindow()

       def initWindow(self):

           self.button=QPushButton("Ok", self)
           self.button.move(100,400)
           self.button.clicked.connect(self.ok)

           self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
           self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
           self.show()

       def ok(self):
           print('close clicked')
           self.close()
   ```